# How to add info from txt file to hash table

Tags: c++

How to implement the addInfo function. We have to find and sort the lines based on their serial number using chaining hash function. But before I need to do addInfo.
For example: the first line "1009 1 "Royal Queen"     2015 160"
the serial number is 1009 and if there is other ships that have the serial number ended with 9 we have to display them together.
Here is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct ShipRecord
{
    int serialNum;
    int shipType;
    string name;
    int year;
    int cap;
    ShipRecord *next;
    ShipRecord(int x)
    {
        serialNum = x;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};
const int SIZE = 10;
class HashMgr
{
    ShipRecord *head = nullptr;
    ShipRecord *tail = nullptr;
public:
    HashMgr()
    {
        ShipRecord * hashTable[SIZE] = {nullptr};

        string line;
        ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open("shipRecords.txt");
        if(myfile.is_open())
        {
            while (!myfile.eof())
            {
                getline (myfile, line);
                addInfo(line);
            }
            myfile.close();
        }
    }
addInfo(string line)
    {}
displayOne(int serialNum)
    {}
displayAll()
    {}
int main()
{
    HashMgr hm;
    hm.displayAll();
    hm.displayOne(1009);
    hm.displayOne(1010);
    hm.displayOne(1019);
    hm.displayOne(1029);
    hm.displayOne(1039);
    hm.displayOne(1014);
    hm.displayOne(1008); /// Prompt a message to that the record does not exist
    hm.deleteOne(1009);
    hm.deleteOne(1039);
    hm.displayAll();
    return 0;
}
/*
Here is the txt.file
  1009 1 "Royal Queen"     2015 160
 1010   2  "Carnival"        2016  1600
 1019  1  "Ocean King"       2013  110
 1029 2 "Royal Prince"     2012 2000
 1039 2 "Royal Princess"  2010 2100
 1014 2 "Royal Caribbean" 2016 1600
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should create Hashtable with key with hash function as number%10 and value should be ShipRecord* but pointing to vector.

While iterating over the file, keep on adding new elements to correct vector based on hash function evaluation.